# Designing a message processing system

Tags: node.js, architecture, redis, message-queue

I have been asked to create a message processing system as following. As I am not sure if this is the right place to post this, feel free to move it to any other appropriate SC group.

**Problem**

Server have about 100 to 500 clients connected at every moment. When a client connects to server, server loads part of their data and cache it in memory for faster access. Server will receive between 200~1000 messages per second for all clients. These messages are relatively small (about 500 bytes). Any changes to data in cache should be saved to disk as soon as possible. When client disconnects all their data is saved to disk and removed from cache. each message contains some instruction and a text message which will be saved as file. Instructions should be executed as fast as possible (near instant) and all clients using that file should get the update. Only writing the modified message to disk can be delayed.

Here is my solution in a diagram

[image: Architecture]

My solution consists of a web server (http or socket) a message queue and two or more instances of file server and instruction server.

- Web server grabs client messages and if there is message available for client in message queue, pushes it back to client.
- Instruction processor grabs instructions from queue and creates necessary message to be processed by file server (Get/set file) and waits for the file to be available in queue and more process to create another message for client.
- File server only provides the files, either from cache or physical file depending on type of file.

**Concerns:**

- There are peak times that total connected clients might go over 10000 at once and total messages received from clients increase to 10~15K.
  I should be able to clear the queue and go back to normal state as soon as possible (with processing requests obviously).
- I should be able to add extra instruction processors and file servers on the fly without having to shut down the other instances.
- In case file server crashes it shouldn’t lose files so it has to write files to disk as soon as there are any changes and process time is available.
- File system should be in b+ tree format so some applications (local reporting apps) could easily access files without having to go through queue server

**My Solution**

I am thinking of using node.js for socket/web server. And may be a NoSQL database for file server and a queue server such as rabbitMQ or Node_Redis and Redis.

**Questions:**

- Is there a better way of structuring this system?
- What are my other options for components of this system?
- is it possible to run all the instances in same server machine or even in same application (in different thread)?

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of holes here, mostly around the web server "pushing" the message back to the client.  That doesn't really work in a web-based world.  You can try and use websockets, but generally, this ends up being polling based.

I don't know what the "instructions" are to be executed, but saving 1000 500byte messages is trivial.  Many NoSQL solutions boast million+ write per second capacity.  Especially if you let committing to disk to lag.

Don't bother with the queue for the return of the file.  A good NoSQL solution will scale better.  Build out a Cassandra cluster, load test it until it can handle your peak load.

This simplifies your architecture into a 1 or more web servers, clients polling that server for file updates, a queue for submitting "messages" to the "instruction server" (also known as an application server in web-developer terms), and a no-sql database for the instruction server to write files to.

This makes scaling easy, you can always add more web servers, and with a decent cluster size for your no-sql server, you should get to scale horizontally there as well.  Your only real bottleneck is your instruction server queue, which you could always throw more instruction servers at.

Comment: Node.JS can properly handle push messages to client, it is a websocket. Clients are not allowed to directly query the NoSQL, application server (instruction server) should verify requests. +1 for cassandra. now I have an alternate to study. if it can save its files in B+ tree structure, it will be the perfect solution.